# What is a reper (reper bundle)?

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, manifolds, definition

The terms *reper* or *reper bundle* appear a few times in Bakalov/Kirillov's "Lectures on Tensor Categories and Modular Functors", and I vaguely recall having encountered them in a course on gauge field theory. But I have since forgotten their meaning.

Googling "reper bundle" does not yield anything, and no question about these has been asked. I seem to remember that it was some kind of frame or frame bundle?

Comment: The French word répère does in fact mean frame. Moving frame = répère mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a *reper bundle* is a [**frame bundle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_bundle). There are several sources defining a "reper", e.g. [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjO1vaC8PDZAhUyxqYKHewzCN8QFgg1MAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpdfs.semanticscholar.org%2F43ea%2F6f2b6b28a9778d700c7479a3072ac8450997.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2Baq43p6ijSjzxYKAAcMSb):

A local *reper* or *frame* of $E$ over $U \subseteq M$ is a
collection of sections $e_1, . . . ,e_k$ such that for all $p\in U$ the vectors
$e_1(p),\ldots ,e_k(p)$ form a basis of $E_p$. A reper is called global if this
property extends to all $p\in M$.

Comment: This is the craziest coincidence imaginable: One of the authors of the paper you linked is my older brother! Thanks for the reference and this amazing _Zufall_.

Comment: Really? You should have talked about your question with him!:)